# How to use getBlockIndex

Tags: block-editor

I want to create a block with HowTo microdata markup and automatically assign ID to child blocks. I have created a holder as the parent block, and I want to give the first child block `id="step1"`, second block `id="step2"` etc...

I wonder how can I use `getBlockIndex`.  Based on the [block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-block-editor/), the first parameter is `Object: Editor state`.  What is `editor state`?  Where can I find this object?  Should I use `getBlockIndex` for this purpose?

Gutenberg is really fun, but the documentation is really thin right now.

Parent block js (The microdata markup is not correct at the moment)

```
(() => {
    const __ = wp.i18n.__; // The __() for internationalization.
    const el = wp.element.createElement; // The wp.element.createElement() function to create elements.
    const registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType; // The registerBlockType() to register blocks.

    const ServerSideRender = wp.components.ServerSideRender;
    const TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;
    const TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl;
    const InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
    const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor;
    const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;

    //Custom variable
    const allowedBlocks = [ 'custom-blocks/how-to-do' ] ;
    const blockTemplate = [ [ 'custom-blocks/how-to-do', {} ], [ 'core/image' ] ];

    registerBlockType( 'custom-blocks/how-to-do-holder', { // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        title: __( 'How to do holder', 'custom-blocks' ), // Block title.

        category: 'custom_block',
        keywords: [ __() ],
        attributes: {

        },
        supports: {
            customClassName: false,
            className: false,
        },

        edit(props) {

            return el(
                'div', { className: 'how-to-do-block-holder', itemscope: 'itemscope', itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowTo" },
                el('h2', {}, 'How to do'), 
                el ( InnerBlocks,
                {
                    allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                    template: blockTemplate
                } )
            );
        },

        save(props) {

            return el(
                'div', { className: 'how-to-do-block-holder', itemscope: 'itemscope', itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowTo" },
                el('h2', {}, 'How to do'), 
                el ( InnerBlocks.Content,
                {
                    allowedBlocks: allowedBlocks,
                    template: blockTemplate
                } )
            );
        },
    } );
})();
```

Child block js

```
(() => {
    const __ = wp.i18n.__; // The __() for internationalization.
    const el = wp.element.createElement; // The wp.element.createElement() function to create elements.
    const registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType; // The registerBlockType() to register blocks.

    const ServerSideRender = wp.components.ServerSideRender;
    const TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;
    const TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl;
    const InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
    const { RichText } = wp.blockEditor;
    const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
    //Custom varaible
    const pageLink = window.location.href;
    let newPageLink = pageLink;
    //If pagelink contains #
    if( newPageLink.includes('#') ){
    //remove all text after # 
    newPageLink = newPageLink.split('#')[0];
    }

    registerBlockType( 'custom-blocks/how-to-do', { // Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        title: __( 'How To Do', 'custom-blocks' ), // Block title.

        category: 'custom_block',
        keywords: [ __()],
        parent: [ 'custom-blocks/how-to-do-holder' ],
        attributes: {
            steps: {
                source: 'children',
                selector: '.steps',
            },
            stepsname: {
                source: 'children',
                selector: '.stepsname',
            },
        },
        supports: {
            customClassName: false,
            className: false,
        },

        edit(props) {
            const steps = props.attributes.steps;
            const stepsname = props.attributes.stepsname;

            function onChangeSteps( newContent ) {
                props.setAttributes( { steps: newContent } );
            }

            function onChangeStepsname( newContent ) {
                props.setAttributes( { stepsname: newContent } );
            }

            const editSteps = el(
                RichText,
                {
                    tagName: 'p',
                    onChange: onChangeSteps,
                    value: steps,
                    placeholder: __( 'Step...' ),
                    itemprop: 'text'
                }
            );

            const editStepsname = el(
                RichText,
                {
                    tagName: 'p',
                    onChange: onChangeStepsname,
                    value: stepsname,
                    placeholder: __( 'Name of this step' ),
                }
            );

            /*const linkMeta = el(
                'meta',
                {
                    value: stepsname,
                    itemprop: "url",
                    content: newPageLink

                }
            );*/

            return el('div', {
                className: 'steps-wrapper',
                itemprop: 'step',
                itemscope: 'itemscope',
                itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowToStep"
                },

                editStepsname,
                //linkMeta,

                el ( 'div',
                {
                className: 'steps-wrapper',
                itemprop: 'itemListElement',
                itemscope: 'itemscope',
                itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowToDirection"
                },

                editSteps

                )
            );
},
        // The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
        save(props) {
            const steps = props.attributes.steps;
            const stepsname = props.attributes.stepsname;

            const StepsOutput = el ( RichText.Content,
                { 
                tagName: 'p',
                className: 'steps',
                value: steps,
                itemprop: 'text',
                }
                );

            const StepsnameOutput = el ( RichText.Content,
                { 
                tagName: 'p',
                className: 'stepsname',
                value: stepsname,
                itemprop: 'name',
                }
                );

            return el('div', {
                className: 'steps-wrapper',
                itemprop: 'step',
                itemscope: 'itemscope',
                itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowToStep"
                },
                StepsnameOutput,

                el ( 'div',
                {
                className: 'steps-wrapper',
                itemprop: 'itemListElement',
                itemscope: 'itemscope',
                itemtype: "http://schema.org/HowToDirection"
                },
                StepsOutput

                )
            );
        },
    } );
})();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe you should show your code? But basically, `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getBlockIndex( clientId )` would work if you know the *block's `clientId`*.

Comment: I want to create a block with HowTo microdata markup and automatically assign ID to child blocks.  I have created a holder as the parent block, and I want to give the first child block id="step1", second block id="step2" etc...

Comment: You need these step ids always to be recalculated when post is saved? I.e., if you open existing post and rearrange (and/or remove) some steps in block editor and then save it, your resulting step ids should be reordered and assigned from 1 to N?

Comment: @VitautsStočka My use-case is like that. Any idea how that can be achieved?